# ECS : Can systems have sub-systems?

Tags: entity-component-system

I am searching about "sub-systems" in ECS but I don't find any article speaking on that.
Considers this simple example:

```
struct Engine
{
    MoveSystem move_system;
    CollisionSystem collision_system;
    RenderSystem render_system;

    void PhysicsSystem::update()
    {
        move_system.update();
        collision_system.update();
        render_system.update();
    }
}
```

We can make a `physics_system` which will be the aggregation of the `physics_system` and the `collision_system`.

```
void Engine::update()
{
    physics_system.update();
    render_system.update(); // No change
}

struct PhysicsSystem
{
    MoveSystem move_system;
    CollisionSystem collision_system;

    void PhysicsSystem::update()
    {
        move_system.update();
        collision_system.update();
    }
}
```

Is it a bad practice? I could not see any drawback since it looks like just a pure change-big-class-into-many-smalls refactoring without logical changes.

Comment: As a general rule, I'd work under the assumption that everything is permitted until you encounter a specific prohibition or problem. Then ask about that specific problem once you've demonstrated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you can. ECS is just like a "guiding methodology",There is no mandatory rule. You can make your own implementation as needed.
2. Is it a bad practice? Maybe. `PhysicsSystem` is not characterized as a system. It does not focus on entities with certain properties. It is only used to organize some other systems. So maybe `PhysicsSystem` is a **System Group** instead of system. System Group is a common concept in ecs system, usually used to organize the update order. You can search it with "system groups" as key-word instead of "sub-systems".